# Why Update Unit Test during O&M?

Tags: unit-testing

I've worked on 2 software development teams.

The first team did not keep unit tests up-to-date due to:

- lack of time
- lack of skill with a newly introduced unit test tool
- complex code that O&M developers did not fully understand, and thus know how to unit test properly

The second team wants to keep unit tests up-to-date, even during O&M.

What say you?

Comment: I'm afraid that your question isn't practical enough for SO, and will probably lead to discussion. There's no definitive answer to this, and if there is it's probably very "localized".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't diligently keep the unit tests up-to-date during maintenance, they will stop providing value.  It will be expensive to get them back up-to-date at a later time, money your boss isn't likely to want to spend that way.

What you should do is work on squeezing more value from your unit tests.

Use them to introduce your maintenance teams to the code.  Use them to show how they provide examples of how to call the code.  Show the team how to first replicate a bug in a unit test, then use that test to prove when the code is fixed.  Show how the tests prove that when their maintenance activities don't break a lot of other tests, that the other code continues to work fine.  Show how they should strive to make changes that don't break a lot of other tests.

You can also appeal to their sense of self-worth.  Show them how the tests will encourage them to make their changes in a modular fashion, and that they will learn object oriented design principles from this, and how to do test driven development.  If they aspire to better themselves in the software development area, these are the hot skills that employers look for.

Basically, the reasons unit tests are valuable don't go away just because a program goes into maintenance.  If anything, those reasons become more valuable.